# authentication with emberjs and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js, devise

I am using ember js to authenticate with my rails api 
my devise sessions controller

```
module Api
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
   unless params[:email] && params[:password]
  return invalid_params('You need to provide both email and password')
  end

  res = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])

 if res && res.valid_password?(params[:password])
    user = res
  end
 unless user
   unless params[:email] && params[:password]
  return invalid_params('invalid email or password')
  else
   return invalid_params('You need to provide both email and password')
  end 
else
 sign_in user
  user.ensure_authentication_token!
 render json: user ,serializer: UserSerializer ,status: 201
   end
end

protected

 def invalid_params(errorMessage)
 warden.custom_failure!
 render json: { errorMessage: errorMessage }, status: 403
end
end
end
```

my emberjs auth.js

```
Auth =Ember.Object.extend({
auth_token: null,
current_user: null,
signIn: function(params) {

 return Ember.$.post('http://localhost:3001/api/users/sign_in',   params).then((function(_this) {
  return function(response) {
    return _this.set('auth_token', response.auth_token);

  };
})(this));


   },
   signUp: function(params) {
    var mypar = {'user':params};
    var that=this;
        return Ember.$.post('/users', mypar,function(data){
   return that.set('auth_token', data.auth_token);
  });
 },
 signOut: function(){
  promise= Ember.$.ajax("/users/sign_out",{
    type: "DELETE"
});
var that =this;
promise.then(function(){
    that.set("auth_token",null);
});
return promise;
  }

  });

   Remon.Auth =Auth.create();
 $.ajaxSetup({

   beforeSend: function(xhr, options) {
    var encoded_auth_token, header;
   if (Remon.Auth.get('auth_token')) {
    encoded_auth_token = Base64.encode64(Remon.Auth.get('auth_token') + ":X");
    header = "Basic " + encoded_auth_token;
   return xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', header);
  }
 },
error: function(xhr) {
  if (xhr.status === 401) {
  //return window.location = '/#/login';

   }
 }
});
```

sign in and sign up working great also I got the user authentication token from sessions controler but sign in sessions not working as when I tried to get json data to another route 
its not working inpite in the other controller I have these method

```
   module Api
 class ProfilesController < ApplicationController


 before_filter :auth_only?
def index
@profiles =Profile.all
 end 
end 
end
```

in devise.rb 
      config.http_authenticatable = [:token]

and in application_controller.rb

```
   skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }


 def allow_ajax_request_from_other_domains
 headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
  end
```

Comment: witch devise version?

Comment: it was using 2.1.2 and after I upgrading to the latest version and I added the modifications provided by devise ,nothing changed

Comment: ok here you make auth ember object but then where create instance form this object? I think you massed some in your ember logic not in rails

Comment: I removed the authentication from rails controller ,when I reload the ember app data reloaded but when I tried to click the link again data not reloaded

Comment: don't remove authentication just return true always. To check that your ember auth logic work

Comment: I began with angularjs then I removed to ember but I think I will stick back to angular ,it is more stable than ember,ember changes every day with syntax not like angular

Comment: this is not true. But how you want if you feel better with angular then use it. But emberJs is far better in a lot of case. Just invest a little bit more time to understand it and will love it.

Answer (score 1):

(work in progress answer)

[EmberCasts](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1) has a great 2 part video on implimenting client side authentication in Ember. I think this would help with cleaning up the Ember side of the code.

> sign in sessions not working as when I tried to get json data to another route its not working

This makes it sound like your Rails side isn't keeping it logged in, if that is the case, then I'd recommend looking at Devise and making sure you are able to access the API with your token.

I'm going to be implementing Devise + Ember in the next couple of days so I'll update this answer with more information as I figure it out myself.

Comment: thanks for your answer,actually I found another solution but I didn't post it here I will post it and mark your answer as correct